# if(transform.rotation.z < 90) is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm stuck and not sure why. Here is my code I have at the moment:

```
if(rigidbody2D.velocity.y >= 1 && transform.rotation.z < 90)
{
    rigidbody2D.angularVelocity = 200f;

}
else if (rigidbody2D.velocity.y < 0 && transform.rotation.z > -90)
{
    rigidbody2D.angularVelocity = -200f;
}
```

It is all working correctly apart from the transform.rotation.z part, it completely ignores that as if it's not there.

What I want is:

If object velocity is more than one (i.e travelling upwards) AND object rotation is less than 90°, then set angular velocity to 200f.

Else if object velocity is less than -1 (i.e travelling downwards) AND object rotation is more than -90°, then set angular velocity to -200f.

Comment: when you step through it, are the variables set to such values as they should be entering either statement?

Answer (score 6):

The `rotation` value is a Quaternion and not in degree. You may want to use [eulerAngles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) to get the rotation in degree.

So you could use something like:

```
transform.eulerAngles.z < 90
```

You shouldn't use negative values, instead of `-90` use `270`:

```
transform.eulerAngles.z > 270
```

Comment: Ah I see, I haven't really used quaternion and eulerAngles before, how would I change the rotation value into a degree so I can set the max/min angles?

Comment: Just use it like in your example and replace `rotation` with `eulerAngles`

Comment: Hmm.. still doesn't seem to be working. All I'm trying to do is put a max and min rotation of an object, so it can't rotate past 90 and -90.

Comment: @Henry-95 IIRC you can't get negative euler values from quaternions.  At the very least the euler docs state that you `...set the angles to absolute values.`, I would assume if there is a limit on setting angles to a negative value that this also applies to return data.

Comment: @Jerdak I added your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

So I had a problem in Unity with a sprite falling over (I did not want to use fixed angle). So this is what I came up with:

```
public float MaxAngle = 45;
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z > MaxAngle)
    {
        if (transform.eulerAngles.z > (360 - MaxAngle) & transform.localScale.x < 0)
        { }
        else
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Probably more efficient way to do it but it works.
"transform.localScale.x <0)" is because I,m using a Flip for movement.
I hope this helps. Drop me a Nickle if so: 15Ubt8ebgaxQoesCALW8WEMoTEcxxV8KMt